# symfony 5 "the fast track" book bug docker when I execute the command

Tags: docker, symfony, docker-compose

I'm on Ubuntu 20.* and I have the book for symfony 5 "the fast track" (from Fabien Potencier).
But when I try to execute this command below it failed on Docker.

```
symfony new --version=5.0-1 --book guestbook
```

Could you help me, please, to run the command :
"symfony new --version=5.0-1 --book guestbook" without any problem. I don't understand why I have this error :

```
[WEB] Stopping Docker Containers: [ KO ]
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Re-run the command with --debug to get more information about the error
```

this is my consol result when I execute the command :

```
Checking Book Requirements
--------------------------

[OK] Git installed
[OK] PHP installed version 7.4.3 (/usr/bin/php7.4)
[OK] PHP extension "json" installed
[OK] PHP extension "session" installed
[OK] PHP extension "ctype" installed
[OK] PHP extension "tokenizer" installed
[OK] PHP extension "xml" installed
[OK] PHP extension "redis" installed
[OK] PHP extension "intl" installed
[OK] PHP extension "pdo_pgsql" installed
[OK] PHP extension "xsl" installed
[OK] PHP extension "amqp" installed
[OK] PHP extension "gd" installed
[OK] PHP extension "openssl" installed
[OK] PHP extension "sodium" installed
[OK] Composer installed
[OK] Docker installed
[OK] Docker Compose installed
[OK] Yarn installed


    Cloning the Repository
----------------------

Clonage dans '/var/www/symfony5/guestbook'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1170, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1170/1170), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (573/573), done.
remote: Total 1170 (delta 557), reused 1170 (delta 557), pack-reused 0
Réception d'objets: 100% (1170/1170), 4.05 Mio | 1.91 Mio/s, fait.
Résolution des deltas: 100% (557/557), fait.

Getting Ready for the Last Step of the Book
-------------------------------------------

[GIT] Check for not yet committed changes: [ OK ]
[GIT] Check Git un-tracked files: [ OK ]

[GIT] Removing Git ignored files (vendor, cache, ...): [ OK ]
[GIT] Resetting Git staged files: [ OK ]
[GIT] Removing un-tracked Git files: [ OK ]
[WEB] Adding .env.local: [ OK ]
[WEB] Stopping Docker Containers: [ KO ]
Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.

Re-run the command with --debug to get more information about the error
```

When I do the --debug, i have the same result (same error sentences).
My docker is running and it works :

```
docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
```

Comment: Asking the same question multiple times is probably not going to yield useful results.

Comment: the first one was closed no (I don't understand how it works) ? If not I would like to remove the first one. Or if you need something else (information, code etc. ) dont hesitate to ask ! :)

Comment: It seems that symfony failed to stop docker container services. Did you try to run command with sudo? If it works, try to update docker service to allow current user to stop it.

Comment: Thank you I will try this evening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add "me" as a user in docker group (it was not written in doc, or far away from install doc).

Comment: sur windows 10 : barre de recherche `Gestion de l'ordinateur` > `utilisateurs et groupes locaux` > `Utilisateur` > click droit `Nouvel utilisateur`. Ensuite aller dans le dossier `Groupes` > double click sur `docker-users` > en bas `Ajouter` > en bas `Avancé` > `Rechercher` > double click sur `me`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me !
On linux command line :

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```